# PayPal checkout buttons JS to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

I am new to paypal php sdk and I wanted to know how to use php with javascript. Here is the frontend code I use:

```js
paypal.Buttons({
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
      return actions.order.create({
        purchase_units: [{
          amount: {
            value: '0.01'
          }// I am searching for a way to get this
        }]
      });
    },
    onApprove: function(data, actions) {
     //call api to verify the order
    }
  }).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

It works fine but I know that using javascript is not a good idea because the user can edit the informations of the order. For the `onApprove` I used my php code to call the paypal api to verify that the order is payed and the informations are correct but how can I get the informations of the order ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use PayPal Checkout from a server, create two routes, one for 'Create Order' and one for 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). These routes should return/output only JSON data (no other HTML or text)

Pair your two routes with the following approval flow: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/server

Comment: Ok thanks I think I got it but I have a question: can’t the user edit the link of the php file to create an order and change the price ? Or simulate a POST to confirm the payment ?

Comment: Your server will have to sanitize its input as far as setting up a transaction with the right price. Don't create any order you don't want to process.  Payments should only be "confirmed" by your second route when you receive a successful capture response from PayPal, which won't happen if anything is "simulated"

Comment: So when the `onApprove` function is called I have to check that the order is valid and that the price is correct ?

Comment: No. Check those things on your server when the order is created. From onApprove, call your server to capture the order.

Comment: I don't really understand . So the javascript calls my php file to get the infos of the order, creates it with the paypal api, and runs the onApprove function when the transaction is finished. But if someone changes the path of the file creating the order he could just use the same json pattern and change the price.

Comment: The javascript calls your php file, which creates the order with the PayPal API. Your server returns the id of the order, which is all the javascript uses.  The payer approves this id, and that will immediately run onApprove once the order is approved. At this point there is no transaction. Your server must use the id to run a capture which (if successful) creates the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

### I'm Guessing You want to add paypal payment to PHP Application

https://paypal.github.io/PayPal-PHP-SDK/sample/
**You can find All info in here :)**

Comment: That SDK and the v1/payments API it uses are both deprecated